# How to securely configure s3 for website access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, permissions, public, bucket

I want to setup an s3 bucket securely but provide public access to website assets such as images, pdfs, documents, etc. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to do this.

I have tried setting up a new bucket which has Block Public Access enabled. I assume this is the best way to secure the bucket but can't enable viewing/downloading of files in this bucket.

I expect to be able to view/download website files from a browser but always get an Access Denied error.

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirements? Are you saying that you have some files that can happily be made public (so _anyone_ can access them), but you also want part of the bucket to be kept private? Or are you saying that you'd like to programmatically determine whether users can access content on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: So I have files that are all fine being public, ie non-sensitive that I want available to the public. I'm surprise Amazon doesn't have a predefined setup for this purpose when u create a bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All content in Amazon S3 buckets are private by default.

If you wish to provide public access to content, this can be done in several ways:

- At the **Bucket level** by providing a **Bucket Policy**: This is ideal for providing access to a whole bucket, or a portion of a bucket.
- At the **Object level** by using an Access Control List (ACL): This allows fine-grained control on an object-by-object basis.
- Selectively, by creating a **pre-signed URL**: This allows your application to determine whether a particular application user should be permitted access

All three methods allow an object in Amazon S3 to be accessed via a URL. This is totally separate to making API calls to Amazon S3 using AWS credentials, which would allow control at the user-level.

Based on your description, it would appear that a **Bucket Policy** would best meet your needs, such as:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"PublicPermission",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is saying: *Allow anyone to get an object from my-bucket*

Note that the policy specifies which calls are permitted, so it can allow upload, download, delete, etc. In the above example, it is only allowing `GetObject`, which means objects can be accessed/downloaded but not uploaded, deleted, etc.

The `/*` in the Resource allows further control by specifying a path *within* the bucket, so it would be possible to grant access only to a portion of the bucket.

When using a Bucket Policy, it is also necessary to **deactivate Block Public Access** settings to allow the Bucket Policy to be used. This is an extra layer of protection that ensures buckets are not accidentally made publicly accessible.

If, on the other hand, your actual goal is to keep content private but selectively make it available to application users, then you could use a **pre-signed URL**. An example is a photo website where people are permitted to view their private photos, but the photos are not publicly accessible.

This would be handled by having users **authenticate** to the application. Then, when they wish to access a photo, the application would determine whether they are **permitted** to see the photo. If so, the application would generate a [pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html) that grants temporary access to an object. Once the expiry time is passed, the link will no longer work.

Comment: Thank you very much John, this is very useful. As this bucket is only used for website assets then the bucket policy approach will work fine. However, users require to upload to this bucket as well. Eg. We store company logos against company profiles, the user is required to upload the image and/or delete it.

How can I modify the bucket policy to allow for this?

Comment: Also, is there a bucket policy that will only allow uploads if performed from our website url? Ie. The upload/delete must be performed via our website portal only.

Comment: It is unwise to permit "public uploads" because then _anybody_ could upload anything. Instead, it is better for your application to authenticate the user, then permit [Uploading Objects Using Presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) to ensure the upload is authorized.

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein,

My S3 Bucket is public and anyone can access my website there. However, one of my servers is using a lot of security measures and I am whitelisting the IP addresses that I want to visit on the website. Thus, I have to add specific IP address in my firewall, but it seems that the S3 Bucket is using multiple servers and it changes. Do you know what IP addresses I have to allow in order to access the website from my server?

Comment: @Vitomir It is not possible to whitelist Amazon S3 via IP addresses. You would need to use another method (eg using AWS credentials). Feel free to create a new Question with full details, rather than asking via a comment on an old Question.